# Vuetify; get the root element of a v-select field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

In a vuetify driven project i have the following select select element;

```
<v-select 
        v-model="$root.$data.currentStudent.LivingConditions" 
        :disabled="!editing" 
        :items="$root.$data.livingconditions" 
        field="@SecurityHelper.SimpleCrypt("LivingConditions")"
        label="Bopæl" item-text="text" item-value="value" 
        @@change="SaveChange2"
></v-select>
```

In the `SaveChange2` event I need to get the value of the attribute "field", but as the `event.target` is not a child of the sending element, I can't figure out how to do this..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send arguments to a handler as follows:

```
@change="handler($event, someArg)"
```

This way it will be executed with the `event` as first argument and whatever you send as second.

In your case (and I assume you use two `@@` due to some template engine):

```
@@change="SaveChange2($event, $root.$data)"
```

And `SaveChange2` could be:

```
methods: {
  SaveChange2(evt, data) {
    console.log('event is', evt);
    console.log('field is', data.field); // equivalent to $root.$data.index
  }
}
```

Comment: YEp..  Thnak you.. $event made the difference